# Module AngularJS loading-bar doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, module

I am trying nodeJS, SailsJS & Angular. I want use this loading bar:
http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/
https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar

I read the loading bar handle http request are automatically.
so i do this :

```
npm install angular-loading-bar.
```

I put the jss and css in assets.

Here my LoginModule :

```
var LoginModule = angular.module('LoginModule', ['angular-loading-bar']);
```

And my LoginController :

```
angular.module('LoginModule')
    .controller('LoginController', LoginController);

LoginController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'cfpLoadingBar'];

function LoginController($scope, $http, cfpLoadingBar) {

    // Get CSRF token and set as header
    $http.defaults.headers.post['X-CSRF-Token'] = document.getElementsByName('_csrf')[0].value;

    $scope.submitLoginForm = function() {
        $scope.start();
        $http.post('/login', {
                identifiant: $scope.login.identifiant,
                password: $scope.login.password
            })
            .then(function onSuccess() {
                window.location = '/home/';
            })
            .catch(function onError(response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
    }

    $scope.start = function() {
        cfpLoadingBar.start();
    };
    $scope.complete = function() {
        cfpLoadingBar.complete();
    };
}
```

But when i login on my form :

```
  <div class="container-fluid" ng-app="LoginModule" ng-controller="LoginController" ng-cloak>
    <div class=" col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Connexion</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <h5 class="col-lg-12" style="text-align: center">Admin !</h5>
          <form ng-submit="submitLoginForm()" class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6 form-group" name="loginForm">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLogin" name="inputLogin" placeholder="Identifiant" ng-model="login.identifiant">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" name="inputPassword" placeholder="Mot de passe" ng-model="login.password">
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right">Connexion</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= _csrf %>">
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I don't see the loading bar when i submit the form (form working) :( why ? Also when i try to load ngAnimate in LoginModule i have an error

I tried also  the function start() on element HTML but nothing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Must include `angular-animate.min.js` to make it work
as also include in git repository example. when I removed this line

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
```

it stopped working please make sure you include animation file. that's why `ngAnimate` also giving error

Comment: thanks for your help i include, the file and now i have the module ngAnimate without error, but the loading bar always don't work :(

Comment: My bad, was the order of include files  it's woking now thanks  ! :)